# Neo4j - Performance on path query

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have to found all paths between two nodes. The length of each path has to be beetween 1 and 5 ( 2 and 3 for this exemple ).

So i'm using this query :

```
profile match p = (a:Station {name : 'X'} ) - [r*2..3] -> (b:Station {name : 'Y'} ) return distinct p
```

I have an index on :Station(name)

but when I profile this query I have this result :

[image: my query's profile]
So the problem is neo4j takes every relationship possible for this node B and then filters using the name. Is it a way for just taking the relation which involved this two specific nodes ?

Comment: Do you have different types of relationships between these nodes? Are you using Labels on your relationships? Do you have Indexes set on name property? http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-schema-index.html

Comment: As said, I have an index on :Station(name)
Every node in my graph are Station
Yes i have 3 different kind of relationship.

Comment: Oh did not see this, my bad, what about the two other questions? :)

Comment: Sorry mate, was edited my answer :x 
How can i know if I have labels on my relationships ? not my db and i'm a beginner with neo4j :x

Comment: `match a-[r]-b return type(r)` will return the list of relationship types you actually have. I think you have to use relationship types to avoid getting every relationships when you actually need only one.

Comment: I don't want only one type of relation. I want every paths between 2 nodes regardless to the type of the relationship.

Comment: Actually I think this can be a little bug, even with USING INDEX the index on the Station b will not be used

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you might want to use `allShortestPaths` for that, eg :

```
PROFILE MATCH p=allShortestPaths((n:Person {name:'Ian Robinson'})-[r*1..5]–(b:Person {name:'Michal Bachman'}))
RETURN p
```

[image]

Comment: But what is actually the difference between Shortest Paths and every path ? I'm affraid to miss some paths